# How to run 2 specific threads at a time? like platform.runLater() and some other thread

Tags: java, javafx

My thread method looks like,

```
public void run(){
    int loop=100;
    int time=5;
    long StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    for(int i=0;i<loop;i++){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() { 
    r2.setWidth(r2.getWidth()+1);
    }
    });
    try{
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if((time < ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - StartTime)))
        loop=0;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    }
}
```

somewhere in my code i created thread as follow.

```
CustomThread thread[]=new CustomThread[3];
double len[]={30,60,90};
for(int i=0;i<thread.length;i++){
    thread[i]=new CustomThread(len[i]);
    thread[i].start();
/*  try{
    thread[i].join();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}*/
}
```

I want thread[i] to complete it's execution and after this  other thread[i+1] will be completing it's execution. By thread[i].join(); i want the other threads to stop for this thread execution except the platform.runLater() thread which get stop when i call join().Overall i want platform.runLater() to continously execute with the current thread. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just use multiple `KeyFrame`s

Comment: @fabian can you give little demo? i'm newbie in programming

Comment: @fabian can you tell how can i access flag variable in lambda expression. Using that i can solve the problem. But the problem in doing that is compliation error occur saying " local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"

Comment: A question related to a single external link is going to go stale in no time. Can you expand on this question to make it clear what you want to so, what you have tried, including a [mcve] and what results you get?

Comment: That video will be a dead link sooner rather than later, and questions should be self-contained. You should [edit] this question into a suitable format for this site.